# How do I Insert a String That Starts With = Into a Cell Value Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am working on a script that inserts various types of data into a worksheet (ws).

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim Index_Array(0 to 5) As Variant
Dim i as Integer

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Index_Array(0) = "This is some text."
Index_Array(1) = "This is also some text."
Index_Array(2) = "22004"
Index_Array(3) = 42
Index_Array(4) = 2.34657
Index_Array(5) = "=55"       'Yes, this should in fact be a string, not a formula or a number

For i = LBound(Index_Array) To UBound(Index_Array)
    ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Index_Array(i)
Next i
```

The problem is when I try to insert the string `=55` into cell A5, it gives me

> Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

The script is all working perfectly fine except in this case, and I believe it is because it is trying to make it a formula. I don't want to force everything to start with a `'` character because not everything is a string. Is there an easy way to make Excel accept a string that starts with an equal sign as a cell value?

Comment: Because Excel treats it as formula. You need to add apostrophe if you want first character to be `=` or format cell as `Text`.

Comment: In your for loop you could check if the string starts with = and could add an apostrophe. This would be a simple if statement using Left(string, 1) to check for =.

Comment: If I insert that apostrophe into the cell, will that just affect the way Excel displays the value, or will it actually affect other things that try to use it, e.g. string concatenation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adds a ' in front of each array item and makes it a text in the Excel UI.

so

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Index_Array(0 To 5) As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Index_Array(0) = "This is some text."
Index_Array(1) = "This is also some text."
Index_Array(2) = "22004"
Index_Array(3) = 42
Index_Array(4) = 2.34657
Index_Array(5) = "=55"

For i = LBound(Index_Array) To UBound(Index_Array)
    ws.Cells(1, i + 1).value = "'" & Index_Array(i) ' add a "'" to make it a text value in excel UI
Next
```

Comment: Adding the `'` in front of any value that was a string solved that problem, and I also verified that trying to read the values back from the cells gives you the values you would expect without that leading `'`. As an added benefit, this also fixes the same issue if your string has an intentional leading apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way is to turn your value to string from first point.
**first way:**

```
Index_Array(5) = "'=55"
```

or

```
Index_Array(5) = cstr("'=55")
```

if you can't change the data when defining it, and only you want this happens to your data starting with `=`, use an if with `left(array(i),1) = "="` and add `"'"` to first of that:

```
For i = LBound(Index_Array) To UBound(Index_Array)
    if left(array(i),1) = "=" then 
        ws.Cells(1, i + 1).value= "'"& array(i)
    else 
        ws.Cells(1, i + 1).value = array(i)
    end if
next i
```

Regards,
M

Comment: The value inside the `CStr` function needs to be wrapped in double quotes, but `CStr("'" & Index_Array(5))` would work.

Comment: yes that was a typo, but anyway, my suggestion was to change the value, not change the way to write it to the cell, ;-)

Answer (score -1):

## General vs Text

When you have the general format in the cells:

```
For i = LBound(Index_Array) To UBound(Index_Array)
    If i = 5 Then
      ws.Cells(1, i + 1).NumberFormat = "@"
      ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Index_Array(i)
     Else
      ws.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = "'" & Index_Array(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I think such a condition which relies on the position of a variable in the array is a very false way of coding! I assume the above code is just an example, so we have to provide a more common solution. Also OP wants it as a string value, Numberformat just changes it's appearance, not value.